# Launch Image Not showing in iPad xamarin forms

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.forms, splash-screen

In my code, I need to implement the launch image for iOS. For that i have the required images in assets folder. The launch images comes as i expected in mobile and other devices. But for iPad the launch image not showing, Instead of that default image is showing. Also, I have removed the default icons in assets folder and resource folder. Can any one know how to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Enable `iPad` in Properties menu of LaunchImages , then add the corresponding image in LaunchImages .

[image]

[image]

But I strongly recommend you to use [Launch.stroyboard](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/) instead.